# Add invalid class to form-group using VueValidate to bootstrap CSS

Tags: vue.js

How to add invalid class to form-group if the validation fails on input. By default VueValidate adds to the input.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mobile" v-bind:class="{'text-danger': errors.has('mobile')}">Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" v-validate="validation.mobile" class="form-control" v-model="user.mobile" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('mobile') }}</span>
      </div>
```

Currently i am using v-bind:class="{'text-danger': errors.has('mobile')}" on the label and i get red colored label on field error.

If i could add invalid to form-group, it would be better to control with css. Below is my VueValidate Settings

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate,  {
    aria: true,
    classes: true,
    classNames: {
      invalid: 'is-invalid'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a computed function to check errors and return the div's classes

```js
{
  computed: {
    formGroupClass: function () {
      if (this.error.has('mobile') ){
        return ['form-group', 'invalid']
      }
       return ['form-group']
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div :class="formGroupClass">
        <label for="mobile" v-bind:class="{'text-danger': errors.has('mobile')}">Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" v-validate="validation.mobile" class="form-control" v-model="user.mobile" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
        <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('mobile') }}</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Got it. Is there any common solution that is applicable for all form-group. As per your code, i need to write it in each form. Whereas input gets invalid class from VueValidator.